# finding an initial solution with lpSolve in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I would like to use the lpSolve package or the lpSolveAPI to generate an integer solution quickly.

The lpSolve program in R runs until it finds an optimal solution, but this could take a while with the size of the problems I am dealing with.

I am trying to find an initial integer solution to an optimization problem without needing R to run for too long. Ideally I could read out the initial solution that lpSolve produces within seconds for an integer problem. Please let me know if there is a way to get the lp command to stop running after some time and just produce the last solution that it came up with

Comment: Finding a feasible integer solution can take a long time. One way to stop when feasible is to use a dummy objective (all zero coefficients). If performance remains slow, you may want to try a different solver (lpsolve can be much slower than other solvers).

Answer (score 0):

Using `lpSolveAPI`, you can set a timeout:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
lprec <- make.lp(N, M) # intialize problem, N, M define the size
lp.control(lprec, timeout=60)  # set timeout in seconds
...
```